# How to install DeathMatch server on Mac OS X for Counter Strike: Source

Tags: macos, counter-strike-source

I have a Steam account. I have installed *Counter-Strike: Source* on my Mac OS X (using that account).

I am bored with the local servers. How can I set up a DeathMatch server on my copy of *Counter-Strike: Source*?

Please, tell me what to install (if there is something needed to install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Windows User here, I don't know if this software is even available on OSX, but since Valve ported the Source Engine and its games to OSX I'm just gonna assume it is. Someone confirm this please.)

First, you'll need to download and install the *Source Multiplayer Dedicated Server* Tool. You can do this from within your Steam client. Just choose "TOOLS" in the Library section. Screenshot:

[image]

It even has a fancy GUI:

[image]

I highly recommend reading one of the many tutorials on setting up a dedicated server. [This one](http://www.cstrike-planet.com/tutorial/1) seems detailed enough.

**However, if this software isn't available on OSX**, then you'll have to install a whole bunch of other software, like macports (to then get wine) to get it running. [The GMod Wiki has a guide for this](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/?title=MacOSX_Dedicated_Server_Setup), which can also be applied to CS:S. (Also, see [page 5 of the tutorial I linked to above](http://www.cstrike-planet.com/tutorial/1-Linux-Install-CS-Source/5))

This is advanced stuff though, and can be rather frustrating if you don't know what you're doing. I recommend searching for a good server instead.

Hope this helps.